# Finite groups of meromorphic functions

Tags: gr.group-theory, meromorphic-functions

Which finite groups are isomorphic to groups of meromorphic functions on the whole complex plane under composition?

Comment: Of meromorphic function on what?

Comment: To be in a group under composition, the meromorphic functions in question have to be injective. This implies they have to be rational, and in fact they have to be Mobius transformations. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1297661/127263)

Comment: I note that this question is getting close votes, but I like it just because the answer is so beautiful.

Comment: The have to be Mobius transformations, so they have to be rotations of the Riemann sphere, so they are the finite groups known since Plato.